# Append not accepting Attributes in Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, attributes, append

Working in sharepoint and currently having trouble with managing dynamic tables using jquery.

I used append(), but when I put some attributes along with the elements it wont accept my code.

here it is:

```
$('#matters_table tr:last-child').append('<tr><td class="classhere"><input type="text"></input></td></tr>');
```

Most of us know that this would fire fine:

```
$('#matters_table tr:last-child').append('<tr><td><input ></input></td></tr>');
```

But in my case i want to add attributes to it, and even add some `styles="width:95%"` inside the  tags. pls help. I am new to jquery. I'm not that familiar with it.

Comment: You should use after... not append

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/p67ssg8d/1/ - looks fine

Comment: using `after` - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/p67ssg8d/2/

Comment: **$('#matters_table tr:last-child').after('<tr><td class="classhere"><input type="text"></input></td></tr>');**  

correct?

Comment: yes.... see the fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pardon me, Now I know why my codes are spitted out in the form. 
It is because of SHarepoint, it was not a jquery problem.

double quotes are messing my codes up

instead of:

```
$('#matters_table tr:last-child').append('<tr><td class="classhere"><input type="text"></input></td></tr>');
```

it should be:

```
$('#matters_table tr:last-child').append('<tr><td><input type='text'></input></td></tr>');
```

anyway thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 0):

You would `.append()` to the table, or `.after()` to the last row.  Right now you're trying to `.append()` the last row, which is effectively trying to nest a new row INSIDE of your row.

Should be as simple as:

```
$('#matters_table').append('<tr><td class="classhere"><input type="text"></input></td></tr>');
```

Or:

```
$('#matters_table tr:last-child').after('<tr><td class="classhere"><input type="text"></input></td></tr>');
```

Personally, I feel appending to the table is cleaner.